# How to find the location of the highest element in a tensor in mathematica

Tags: sorting, matrix, wolfram-mathematica, max

I have a very large array of numbers in the form of a third order tensor.I want to find the highest of all the values in that tensor. How can I do it in mathematica? The context is that a reaction is carried out by varying temperature pressure and vessel volume. I want to find the optimum combination of the three to maximize the product. Each element of the tensor represents a value of the product produced corresponding to a specific combination of temperature pressure and volume.

Answer (score 1):

Given some matrix, tensor, or basically any list-of-lists of real numbers, you can simply use the `Max` function to determine the maximum value and then `Position` to say where it is. Assuming your data isn't enormous (requiring some conservative/careful approach to save time/memory), this should be fine.

For example, here is a random list of lists of of lists of reals:

```
data = Table[RandomReal[],
 {i, 1, RandomInteger[{4, 8}]},
 {j, 1, RandomInteger[{4, 8}]},
 {k, 1, RandomInteger[{4, 8}]}
];
```

You can just do:

```
m = Max[data]
Position[data, m]
```

This will tell you the position of the maximum value. If you did random integers instead, you could have ties, in which case you might have repeats:

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 10}],
 {i, 1, RandomInteger[{4, 8}]},
 {j, 1, RandomInteger[{4, 8}]},
 {k, 1, RandomInteger[{4, 8}]}
];
m = Max[data]
Position[data, m]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Table[RandomInteger[100, 3], 3]  

Prepend[Ordering[%[[First[Ordering[Reverse@*Sort /@ %, -1]]]], -1], 
 First[Ordering[Reverse@*Sort /@ %, -1]]]
```

% stands for the tensor to sort, in this case it's a random tensor generated from `Table[RandomInteger[100, 3], 3]`

Answer (score 0):

This gives the position and value in one shot.

```
(m = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 3, 2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
First@MaximalBy[
    Flatten[MapIndexed[ {##} &, #, {-1}], ArrayDepth[#] - 1], 
    First] &@m
```

> {0.903213, {3, 2, 2}}

Here is an alternate that will work with ragged lists:

```
 Module[{h}, 
    First@MaximalBy[List @@@ Flatten[MapIndexed[h@## &, #, {-1}]], 
    First]] &@{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, {2, 3}}}
```

> {5, {2, 2}}